# HTML5 canvas adding dots/circles to canvas line - can i combine lines and circles to 'join the dots'?

Tags: html, canvas, line, geometry

I've made 2 Line paths with 'lineTo' which change direction at various points - these have plotted fine. These lines are rendered by canvas, not svg.

I need to add circles at the points in the lines where they change direction, namely at the lineTo points e.g: context.lineTo(149, 50). This would look like joining dots.

I don't know how to add these dots to the lines or if it is possible - can anyone advise please?

Thanks in advance. See below for the markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      // attributes
      context.lineWidth = 2;
      context.lineJoin = 'round';

      // left line
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(10, 20);
      context.lineTo(149, 50);
      context.lineTo(50, 100);
      context.lineTo(149, 150);
      context.lineTo(109, 200);     
      context.strokeStyle = "red";
      context.stroke();

      // right line
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(10, 20);
      context.lineTo(109, 50);
      context.lineTo(60, 110);
      context.lineTo(109, 150);
      context.lineTo(85, 200);
      context.strokeStyle = "blue";
      context.stroke();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a specific function for drawing dots at turning points of a path, but why not drawing circles where you want them by yourself?

You can simply draw circles on the direction-changin-points by using the arc() method ([here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-circles/) well explained). As you already know the coordinates from the lineTo() points, this should be a piece of cake ;)

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back - checked the link you added but strangely this isn't dropping the circle in. 
Can see how it should be a piece of cake and had tried this sort of thing already so i think i must just be dropping syntax or something obvious somewhere.
Will hit again later.
Cheers

Comment: Worked with a bunch of tinkering, which i'm still doing, thanks! 
I had to make the dots: context.stroke(); otherwise when there are 3 or more they completed a shape and block out the space with colour - basically they made triangles between every 3 dots.
    `context.beginPath();
  context.arc(10, 20, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.arc(149, 50, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.arc(50, 100, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.stroke();`

Comment: Just discovered another technique which gets around the 'triangle' problem which uses beginPath/closePath. Here's an example:
    `var ctx = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.arc(50, 20, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();`

Comment: found that last solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184475/drawing-different-colored-shapes-in-a-path-html5-canvas-javascript